# How to add delay in react native start activity

Tags: android, react-native

In my React Native app, I would like to pause the MainActivity starting to be able to display a logo few seconds.

I can't find how to do it. I tried several things.

I tried something like that in `MainApplication.java`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  Thread.sleep(2000); 

  super.onCreate();
  SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
}
```

But it results in compilation errors.

How to pause execution for 2 seconds ?

Comment: Why not show the logo in the first React Native screen?

Comment: I use the appBackground as splash screen and it blinks before activity start. But I might end into using your solution if I don't find anything else

Comment: How is your splash screen implemented? If it is implemented as a separate activity, you can easily add a delay and then route it to your desired activity.